# MVC3 Ajax UpdateTargetId bypassed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a MVC View that generates multiple `Ajax.BeginForm`, with a button in them that calls a function in the Controller that returns a Partial View. The `UpdateTargetId` is set to the ID of a Div. It works fine if I manually click the button, but if I use this code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submitButton").click();
    });
</script>
```

Then it clicks the button alright, but it opens the Partial View in a new page... Why does this happen, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to submit the form directly, instead of clicking the submit button. perhaps

```
$('#formID').submit();
```

Will help with what you're after.